# what is the escape oracle sql sequence while inserting a record?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm inserting a record in oracle database, where I'm taking values from a java bean. It goes like this::

```
insert into allergy (patient_id, allergy, reaction) values(seq_patient.nextval, '" + bean.getPatient_allergy() + "', '"+ bean.getReaction()+"')";
```

But the values for allergy can gave an apostrophe which causes the sql to fail with ORA-00917: missing comma. is there any way to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use parameterized statements instead of injecting variables into a query:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use [bind variables](http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_bind_variables.html) in preference to building your query as a string.

That'll take care of your problem. It will also prevent [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (also, see [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)).

Here is some info on how to use prepared statements and bind variables in Java: [link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Answer (score 0):

How about using parameterized query instead of assembling the `INSERT` command? Tha would also fix your current [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerability.